# Селектор... Получает пустой список, вместо полного

Tags: python, css-selectors

В общем и целом, решил научиться парсить. Сделал небольшой парсинг одного сайта - все получилось, но в этот раз я не понимаю что не так. body он получает данные, а дальше -  нет. Выводит просто пустой список []. `Я хочу, чтобы он выводил все рецепты, которые есть на странице`

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def some():
    while True:

        r = requests.get('https://lenta.com/recepty/catalog-recepty/')
        html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
        up_d = html.select(".recipe-grid")
        print(up_d)
        time.sleep(3600)

some()
```

Comment: "Сделал небольшой парсинг одного сайта - все получилось" это видимо был статический сайт, а на данный момент вы пытались спарсить динамический caйт.

Comment: Это никак не решить?

Comment: Попробуйте решить через селенимум.